# Permission Inheritance Problems on Shared Folders - Windows Server 2003

Tags: permissions, windows

I'm having a problem with file and folder permissions not inheriting.
I've set the permissions on the main folder but the permissions are not inheriting down to the sub-folders and files. Even if I set full control permissions directly for a user, that user is still unable to write to that directory or modify the files inside. When I go into security properties, permissions are there and set, but don't seem to be applying.

Answer (score 2):

To propagate folder permissions down a structure, you must use the *Advanced* dialog.  When viewing the permissions tab of the advanced dialog, *edit* the **access control entry (ACE)** that you wish to have propagate down the hierarchy; ensure that *"Apply onto:"* is set to *"This folder, subfolder and files"*.  Afterwards, tick the *"Replace permission entries on all child objects with entries show here that apply to child objects"* to propagate the permissions down the folder hierarchy.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I've tried that. The permissions are already applied to the folder, subfolders and files. When I try the "replace permission entries on all child objects..." it get an error stating Access Denied for certain files and folders.

Comment: If you're receiving an access denied error, the odds are you don't have the proper permissions to change all child objects down the hierarchy.  It is likely that you'll have to take ownership and propagate ownership changes down the path.  This is also completed on the Advanced dialog.  You'll need to click the owner tab and choose your user account or a security group you belong to and tick the Replace owner on subcontainers and objects box.  This will give you owner-level permissions (full) on the object and all child objects.  'Ok' to close all dialogs after the owner change and retry.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it by opening "Computer Management">"Shared folders" and giving the local Admin full control of the share. I also assigned the user her permisions from the same console and it worked fine